# I can print to file using > in terminal but how do I print to files where I create the name using a $ in this code

Tags: string, perl, file, printing

I can print to file using > in terminal but how do I print to files where I create the name using a $ in this code?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $calls_dir = "Ask/";
opendir(my $search_dir, $calls_dir) or die "$!\n";
my @files = grep /\.txt$/i, readdir $search_dir;
closedir $search_dir;
print "Got ", scalar @files, " files\n";

#my %seen = ();
foreach my $file (@files) {
    my %seen = ();
    my $current_file = $calls_dir . $file;
    open my $FILE, '<', $current_file or die "$file: $!\n";


    while (<$FILE>) {
        #if (/phone/i) {
        chomp;
        #if (/phone\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
        #if (/^phone\s*:\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
        #if (/Contact\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
        if (/^*(.*)Contact\s*(.*)\r?$/i) {
            $seen{$1} = 1;
            print $file."\t"."$_\n";# I want to print this line to file named $file."result".txt
            #print "\t";
            #print "\n";
            #print "$_\n";
            #print "\t";
            #print "\n";
            foreach my $addr ( sort keys %seen ) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
    close $FILE;
}
```

Comment: I do not believe that the questions you've asked in the last 8 days are serving you yet.  You appear to be somewhat lost in your approach, and perhaps suffering from [XY Problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) or at minimum a language barrier.  I would suggest getting back to basics when you pose your next problem.  To state exactly what you're trying to accomplish in words first, both big picture and for the specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open a filehandle for writing to that file and print to it. If it doesn't exist, Perl will create it.

```
open my $fh, '>', "${file}result.txt" or die $!;
$fh->print("$file\t$_\n");
```

From `perldoc -f open`:

```
If MODE is ">", the file is opened for
output, with existing files first being truncated ("clobbered")
and nonexisting files newly created. If MODE is ">>", the file is
opened for appending, again being created if necessary.
```

If you want to avoid truncation, check if it exists first using `-e` and/or add something to the filename to make it reasonably unique (like a Unix timestamp).